# SQL Server Row size

Tags: sql-server, pivot

We are creating this crosstab report.. Generating query at time in SQL Server 2008.

In one of selection when user make Program Name as a column it is giving below error:

Creating or altering table 'FakeWorkTable' failed because the minimum row size would be 11852, including 189 bytes of internal overhead. This exceeds the maximum allowable table row size of 8094 bytes.

Query shall return like:
Date Program 1 ... Program 100... Program 500

It will tell some information about TV program datewise.

Is there any way to increase this row size?

Please let me know in-case any other information is needed.

Best Regards

Comment: What are the types of the program columns?

Comment: `SELECT LEFT 500 * FROM dbo.WishfulThinking`

Comment: Do you really need SQL Server to return all 500 columns?  Why not do this type of transformation in your presentation layer?

Comment: If you need 500 columns you're doing it wrong.  There's no reason you can't return `DATE, ProgramSequence, ProgramName` for this.

Comment: `PIVOT` doesn't work unless you have more than 1000 columns.

Comment: Learn more about database normalization

Comment: What does your code look like?  You're asking people to help you while blind to what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions :). Sorry I was on on leave yesterday.
It seems my question has not been understood correctly. It is a Crosstab report in which row data can be shown as columns (as Pivot table) as it gives u a better picture. Program Name in a TV program on which Advertisement runs (its a media company project). Program name is not a column in a database it is a row which turn into a column while viewing as crosstab. Program name number not quite fixed as it depend on the Campaign for that month or client. Database is very much normalized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Code as below:**

```
set @query 
      = 'SELECT ' + @PivotRowColumn + ',' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            SELECT ' + @SelectCalculationColumn  + ', ' + @PivotRowColumn + ', ' + @PivotColumn + '
            FROM ##ResultCrosstab
            --where programName like ''S%''
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            ' + @CalculateColumn + '
            for ' + @PivotColumn + ' in (' + @cols + ')
         ) p '
```

**@PivotRowColumn/@PivotColumn** can be anything out of (SalesHouse/Station/Day/Week/Month/Date/Product/Program/SpotLength/Timeband/Campaign. 
**@SelectCalculationColumn** is a KPI e.g Spots/Budget/Impacts/Variance/TVR etc.
**@cols** are column

This issue comes very rarely for bigger campaigns. I have added a drop down in-case user select programs as column. So in-case user gets error they can limit the program or use Filter (which is already in place)

Comment: And for bigger reports we will be creating a SSAS cube